# Why I have to add a reference of System.Speech?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, system.speech.recognition

I am new to VisualStudio.

Why I have to add a reference to System.Speech and can not use it by a using directive instead?

Comment: Because it is in a namespace inside an assembly which isn't references by your project.

Answer (score 1):

C# `using` statement does not reference any assemblies.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664766(v=vs.71).aspx),

> A using-namespace-directive imports the types contained in a namespace into the immediately enclosing compilation unit or namespace body, enabling the identifier of each type to be used without qualification.

In other words, this line:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

just allows you to use

```
Color x = Color.AliceBlue;
```

instead of

```
System.Drawing.Color x = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
```

At the same time, you still need to add a reference to the used assembly in order to build your solution.